# PHP Slideshow from Javasript base (for Garry's Mod)

Tags: javascript, php, garrys-mod

I'm currently working on a loading screen for a Garrys Mod Server and apparently the integrated browser is not able to execute Javascript (Is this true? Does anyone know more about it?).

My server-provider told me to use PHP, but unfortunately I don't know anything about it. I have written a slideshow with Javascript before and maybe there is an easy way to "convert" it to Php. Is it even possible to create a slideshow purely with Php? As I said, I really don't know anything about it and I don't have the time to learn it at the moment.

Javascript:

```js
let i = 0;
let images = [];
const slideTime = 3000; // ./1000 = seconds

images[0] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/14/20/11/japanese-cherry-trees-324175_1280.jpg';
images[1] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_1280.jpg';
images[2] = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/12/15/02/53/flower-3876195_1280.jpg';


/// ---------- BackgroundPicture -----------

function changePicture() {
    {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";

        i < images.length - 1 ? i++ : i = 0;

        setTimeout(changePicture, slideTime);
    }
}

/// ---------- WindowOnlaod -----------

window.onload = () => {
  changePicture()
}
```

(code works on webspace)

If someone knows a simple solution I'm looking forward to an answer.

Comment: PHP does not have UI interaction, so your slideshow can not be converted to PHP

Comment: Have you seen this? https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/Panel:RunJavascript

Comment: You need to know what difference between server side language (backend) or client side language (frontend), here for reference [frontend-vs-backend](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/frontend-vs-backend/amp/)

Comment: @Justinas the slideshow runs automatically, so the player cant interact with it. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @DavidB no, PHP does not manipulate DOM, it's the html per-processor, so there is no way to delay showing content or something. Just no way to do front-end stuff with back-end tools, forget about that!